# Merge tags "hedging" and "hedge"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Description for [hedging](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hedging):

> for questions that relate to hedging. A hedge is an investment position intended to offset potential losses/gains.

Description for [hedge](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hedge):

> A hedge is an investment to reduce the risk of adverse price movements in an asset.

Looks like they're the same thing. Should these tags be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds good to me, I'd propose [hedging](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hedging) should win as it has more posts (101 v 20) and seems more natural.

If anyone prefers [hedge](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hedge) post a competing answer and we can see how the votes go. If there's no disagreement I'll do something in a few days (at least if someone reminds me!) [EDIT: now done]

Comment: If someone types in 'Hedge' would it show 'hedging' as a suggestion? If so, I agree.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon yes - you can see the behaviour with another synonym from [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), e.g. [tag:buybacks]